# Glassfish module deploy fails with "In-place deployment" error message

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3

It was my first time to use Java EE and I am having an error everytime I run my html file.

This is the error I am seeing:

> In-place deployment at C:\Documents and Settings\scybermonde\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Exercises\build\web
>   deploy?path=C:\Documents and Settings\scybermonde\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Exercises\build\web&name=Exercises&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3
>   C:\Documents and Settings\scybermonde\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Exercises\nbproject\build-impl.xml:683: The module has not been deployed.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

What was wrong if I am receiving an error like this?

I also tried to deployed it referring to what it said in the later part "The module has not been deployed" but still the same error appears...

please help... thanks in advance :)

Comment: you may want to look at the output that is in the server log... it should be in a tab near the output from ant that you have quoted above...

Comment: Was this ever resolved? What version of NetBeans?